# Why aren't JobListeners Durable in Quartz.NET?

Tags: quartz.net

I'm trying to chain a few jobs in Quartz.NET through `JobChainingJobListener`. I first create a couple of durable jobs (while using ADO JobStore with SQL Server) and this part works well - the jobs are visible across Quartz.NET restarts.

When I chain my jobs with `Scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(listener, matchers)`the listener fires correctly, but its definition cannot be made durable in the database. After every server restart, I have to define all listeners again.

Looking at the DB tables, there are no tables for listeners, nor does the code for `ListenerManagerImpl` contain any hints of listener persistence.

I'm planning to add listener durability and reload the global listener dictionary on server restart. Before I do that, I'm wondering if there are any reasons why the project does not already do so? Considering how mature Quartz.NET is, someone would have already ran into this, so it seems I'm missing something.

Can anyone please point to any pitfalls in implementing listener durability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Quartz's perspective listeners are just a configuration issue. Just like you configure job store type or other settings for the library. Commonly listeners are stateless and thus need no persistence services, unlike triggers and jobs that hold state that need to be persisted between invocations and possible job processing nodes.

If you have sound configuration management plan this shouldn't be an issue. Just handle the listener configuration like you would other aspects of the setup. If you have state management in your listeners that would need storage between restarts, that's a different story. Then you'd naturally need custom persistence.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It seems as if `JobChainingJobListener` is stateful, considering it only makes sense when associated with configured jobs, which in turn one can create and persist at runtime.

Comment: That's an interesting special case there. But still I feel that chaining is more usable in a "hard-coded" scenario where you define automatic fixed rules for jobs that should trigger. Reading this kind of fixed configuration works as a documentation, in a way.

One option is always to trigger the next job from the original job if the chain is somehow really dynamic.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt reply. Seems more natural to me that the downstream job can listen for upstream instead of the upstream knowing about downstream. Otherwise, every time I want to configure a new job that depends on the upstream I need to change the upstream job definition as well. Guess it will take some adjusting to Quartz philosophy and terminology.

Comment: Indeed, that is the natural flow for modeling. There's just the persistence problem then, but you could write your own version that works based on conventions or JobKey matchers.